# mongodb - Replica set creation error: Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded

Tags: replication, mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I am configuring a mongodb replica set. From my current primary node, when `rs.add('host1:27017')`, it yields this error

```
Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively; failed with Server min and max wire version are incompatible (7,7) with client min wire version (6,6)
```

On my `host1` and `host2` machines, I already added `replication` option with the same `replSetName`, `bind_ip`, and exposed firewall. As a proof, through command line `mongo --host host1` I can still connect to `host1`'s mongo instance. The `telnet` command also yields the same successful connection. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The error message regarding wire protocol version suggests that you are trying to mix 3.6 and 4.0 members in a replica set, where the 4.0 member is likely running with [`featureCompatibilityVersion` set to 4.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#compatibility-enabled). For a new replica set you should ideally start with all members on the same version. Also note that the `bind_ip` option is not a firewall. It should contain the local IPs each instance is listening to, which would generally be different on each instance unless you are using `bindIpAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that all 3 machines must have the same version 4.0